# Rails and jQuery: How to select input from a specific form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I have a rails app with a job model, and on the index page, each job has a form. I need to be able to access the specific form everytime the submit button is selected, so I can take the input for the form and perform some jQuery validation with it.

Here is some of my index.html page.

```
<ul>
  <% @unassigned.each do |job| %>
    <li>
            <div class="row new-message">
              <div class="small-12 columns">
                  <%= form_for @message do |f| %>
                    <%= f.text_area :body, {placeholder: 'enter a new message...'} %>
                    <%= f.hidden_field :job_id, value: job.id %>
                    <%= f.submit 'send message', class: 'button small radius secondary message-button', "data-job-id" => job.id %>
                    <div id="message<%= i %>-validation-errors"> </div>
                  <% end %>
              </div>
            </div>
    <li>
  <% end %>
<ul>
```

And here is the javascript/jQuery where I try to select the input from a specific form

```
var messages;

messages = function() {

    $('.message-button').click(function(e) {
        var id = $(this).data('job-id');
        messageValidation(e, id);
    });

    function messageValidation(e, id) {
        var body = $('#message_body').val();
        var div = '#message' + id + '-validation-errors';
    if(body == "") {
      $(div).html('');
      e.preventDefault();
      $(div).html('<small style="color:red"> Message body empty </small>');
    }
    };

};

$(document).ready(messages);
```

The index page will have a form for each job, and I want there to be front end validation that checks when the button is submitted, that the `body` field is not empty. It works fine the first time, but after going back to the index page, and trying to validate a second time `var body = $('#message_body').val();` always seems to be empty, whether I put anything in the body or not. I believe it has something to do with the fact that since there is the same form for each job, there are multiple `#message_body` id's on the same page, and it is selecting the incorrect one. I am new to jQuery and javascript can someone please help me

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have multiple elements with same id on a page. What you can do is add a `class` identifier to those elements.

In your case, simple set `class="message_body"` to your elements and select them as shown below:

```
$('.message-button').click(function(e) {
    var id = $(this).data('job-id');
    var body = $(this).parent().find('.message_body').val();
    messageValidation(e, body, id);
});
```

Comment: I tried this before my current solution, and this does select a form, but it always selects the first form.

Comment: it will only select the form which contains the button being clicked.

Comment: Whenever I tried that and I put `var id = $('#message_job_id').val();` into the `messageValidation` method, id always comes out as `'1'` no matter which forms submit buttn I click

Comment: I believe this happens because there are many `'#message_job_id'` id's on the page, and everytime it run's it selects the first one it sees. Is there a way to select the correct input from the specific form that was clicked

Comment: `$('#message_job_id')` will always pick the first element that matches the selector `#message_job_id`. so don't use the selector generically. use it in relative to the button you are clicking.

Comment: Yeah, I figured I would have to do something like that, but I am new to jQuery and all of the front end, so I have no idea how to go about doing that

Comment: As i mentioned, try getting the body outside and pass body value to messageValidation() function. Let me know if you face any issues.

Comment: After your suggestion I just tried to get the body and id, in the `$('.new_message').submit` function right before I called `messageValidation` and pass it as a parameter to `messageValidation` but it always seems to be pulling the first ones. I have no idea how to select the body and id of the specific form that is being submitted

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem I needed to select the child of the form and find the message_body through that.

```
messages = function() {

    $('.new_message').submit(function(e) {
        //var id = $(this).data('job-id');
        var $this = $(this);
        var body = $this.children('#message_body').val();
        var id = $this.children('#message_job_id').val();
        messageValidation(e, body, id);
    });

    function messageValidation(e, body, id) {
        var div = '#message' + id + '-validation-errors';
    if(body == "") {
      $(div).html('');
      e.preventDefault();
      $(div).html('<small style="color:red"> Message body empty </small>');
    }
    };

};
```